# mocking os.environ returns, str expected not dict

Tags: python, python-unittest

[image]

Executing this code results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py", line 1630, in __enter__
    self._patch_dict()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py", line 1652, in _patch_dict
    in_dict.update(values)
  File "/Users/<redacted>/<redeacted>/<redacted>/venv/bin/../lib/python3.7/_collections_abc.py", line 841, in update
    self[key] = other[key]
  File "/Users/<redacted>/<redacted>/<redacted>/venv/bin/../lib/python3.7/os.py", line 683, in __setitem__
    value = self.encodevalue(value)
  File "/Users/<redacted>/<redacted>/<redacted>/venv/bin/../lib/python3.7/os.py", line 753, in encode
    raise TypeError("str expected, not %s" % type(value).__name__)
TypeError: str expected, not int
```

Comment: What you're posted isn't syntactically valid. Also the environment is represented as a dictionary of *strings*, so your test double doesn't match the thing it's replacing.

Comment: I think you are trying to pass two urls by mentioning them as dev and test in a dict but that's not the right way.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass the dict with a `key` `URL` which is causing the problem.

See [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) for further approach.

Try below code:

```
import os
import unittest
from mock import patch
with patch.dict('os.environ',{"devUrl":"https://devurl.com","testUrl":"https://testurl.com"}):
     print(os.environ['devUrl'])
     print(os.environ['testUrl'])
```

Comment: The code for which test case has to be written has URL in it. So, I cannot remove it. If I remove URL, I wont get the above mentioned error. But I need URL in it

Comment: You can't use the dictionary that way in `path.dict`. So in order to access it, you need to remove URL and look for a workaround for your test cases.